# Increase all x-coordinates with help of a foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Given a figure of two lines with x and y coordinates, I want to duplicate the figure and increase all x coordinates by the same integer (in this example by 3).
I was trying to use a foreach loop, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (6.5,4.5);
\tikzmath{
    int \x1; int \x2;
    \x1 = 0; \x2 = 2;
}
\draw[black,thick] (\x1,2)  -- (\x2,2);
\foreach \X in {\x1,\x2}{
    \X=\X+3;
}
\draw[black,thick] (\x1,2)  -- (\x2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I guess I'm using the syntax wrong. However I would like to have a code where I only have to change one number (here the 3) and all of my x coordinates change by this number.

Comment: This isn't like a Python (or similar) script, there is no evaluation done in that context. I don't really know how to do this, I guess you don't want `\draw[black,thick,shift={(3,0)}] (\x1,2)  -- (\x2,2);`.

Comment: Oh thanks that also does what I was looking for, even though it is not with a foreach loop ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you tried doesn't work because there is no evaluation in that context. What you instead should do is use a second `\tikzmath`, as in this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (6.5,4.5);
\tikzmath{
    int \x1; int \x2;
    \x1 = 0; \x2 = 2;
}
\draw[black,thick] (\x1,2)  -- (\x2,2);

\tikzmath{
  for \X in {1,2}{
     \x\X=\x\X+3;
  };
}
\draw[black,thick] (\x1,2)  -- (\x2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The more common way of moving one (or more) paths is to use `shift={(x,y)}`, either as an option to a specific path, or to a `scope` environment, like this (the `declare function` stuff is just another way of making constants, you could use the `\tikzmath` stuff as well):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    x1=0;
    x2=2;
  }
]
\draw[gray!40!] (-0.5,-0.5) grid (6.5,4.5);

\draw[black,thick] (x1,2)  -- (x2,2);

\begin{scope}[shift={(3,0)}]
  \draw[black,thick] (x1,2)  -- (x2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples give the same output:

[image]